# What does <<>> mean in Erlang code?

Tags: erlang

In some code I have seen something like this

```
{ok, Req2} = cowboy_req:reply(200, [], <<"Hello World!">>, Req),
```

I can't find out what does those <<>> mean.. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Erlang in they refer to *binaries/bitstrings*, see [Bit Strings and Binaries](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id65994) and [Bit Syntax Expressions](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#bit_syntax).

Answer (score 1):

This is for creating binary sequences. See [relevant documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/bit_syntax.html).